# WSo2IS tutorial kmarketAtrrFinder project code and build

Tags: java, xacml3, wso2-identity-server

Hi As part of investigating both WSO2 IS capability and XACML in itself I am trying to get the KMarket tutorial together. This involves adopting KmarketAttrFinder code and building it before it can be used.  The tutorial itself only supplies individual java files but nothing to configure and build like in the form of e.g. a maven Eclipse project. Lacking this this process is extremely tedious and error prone as it seems to depend on a lot of other code. 
Has someone been through this process once before or can WSO2 perhaps deliver this as part of their tutorial. Because current situation sort of negates the whole purpose 
Thanks 
Peter

Comment: WSO2 Identity Server tracks all the product related queries in https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues. Please create an issue there to suggest this improvement.

Comment: This package should not be a osgi bundle, you can simply use some IDE and create a mvn project and add the java class and build it. A similar packaging can be find in https://github.com/GDRDABARERA/Custom-Grant-Type/tree/master/SimpleJar/custom-grantNew